# Application Error While Deploying with Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, web-deployment

I'm deploying my project to heroku, I create my app push to heroku, adjust my postgreSQL credentials, migrate the DB, but when I "run heroku open", It shows me: Application Error  your page could not be served.

Project structure:

```
├── apps
│   ├── home
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── inventario
│   ├── ordenes_trabajo
│   ├── reportes
│   ├── sucursales
│   ├── usuarios
│   └── ventas_cotizaciones
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── prerequirements_install.txt
├── Procfile
├── proyecto_www
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── settings
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── datepicker
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   ├── pdfs
│   ├── plantilla
│   ├── sass
│   └── syntaxhighlighter
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── base_list.html
│   ├── datatableview
│   └── includes
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proyecto_www.settings.staging")
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

The parameters in my settings are:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
STATICFILES_DIRS=(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'proyecto_www.wsgi.application'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Procfile content is

```
web: gunicorn proyecto_www.wsgi
```

My main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns=[
            url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
            url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.home.urls',namespace='home')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.usuarios.urls',namespace='usuarios')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.inventario.urls',namespace='inventario')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.ventas_cotizaciones.urls',namespace='ventas_cotizaciones')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.ordenes_trabajo.urls',namespace='ordenes_trabajo')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.sucursales.urls', namespace='sucursales')),
            url(r'^', include('apps.reportes.urls', namespace='reportes')),
            ]

urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

My heroku logs are:

```
2016-01-16T16:44:23.261629+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:23 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-01-16T16:44:23.261703+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:23 +0000] [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2016-01-16T16:44:23.285624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=crisefd-concesionario-www.herokuapp.com request_id=195b1b27-df0c-44e2-9e27-c59fd4de17ee fwd="181.52.225.237" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27099ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-01-16T16:44:24.074843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-01-16T16:44:24.074843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-16T16:44:24.062495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2016-01-16T16:44:27.849620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn proyecto_www.wsgi`
2016-01-16T16:44:30.462707+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:30 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
2016-01-16T16:44:30.503069+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2016-01-16T16:44:30.463623+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:30 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:56568 (3)
2016-01-16T16:44:30.463891+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:30 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-01-16T16:44:30.480976+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:30 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712682+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712691+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 20, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712698+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712706+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 20, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714018+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714025+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/proyecto_www/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714032+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714039+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/proyecto_www/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712683+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712691+00:00 app[web.1]:     "'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set "
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712699+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712706+00:00 app[web.1]:     "'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set "
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714019+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714026+00:00 app[web.1]:     from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714033+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714040+00:00 app[web.1]:     from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712671+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:31 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712684+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712692+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set before importing 'whitenoise.django'
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712700+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712707+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set before importing 'whitenoise.django'
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714020+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714027+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 20, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714034+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714041+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 20, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712676+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712684+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712693+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712700+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712803+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:31 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714020+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714027+00:00 app[web.1]:     "'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set "
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714034+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714048+00:00 app[web.1]:     "'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set "
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712678+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712686+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712695+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712702+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714014+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714022+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714029+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714036+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714203+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712677+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712685+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712694+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712701+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714012+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:31 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714021+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714028+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set before importing 'whitenoise.django'
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714035+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714049+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set before importing 'whitenoise.django'
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712679+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712687+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712696+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712703+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714015+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714030+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714037+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-01-16T16:44:31.751764+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:31 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712680+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712688+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712696+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712703+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714016+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714023+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714030+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714037+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.751871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-16 16:44:31 +0000] [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712681+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712689+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/proyecto_www/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712697+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712704+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/proyecto_www/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714017+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714031+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714038+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712681+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712690+00:00 app[web.1]:     from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712698+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.712705+00:00 app[web.1]:     from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714018+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714025+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714032+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-01-16T16:44:31.714039+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-01-16T16:44:32.508739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-01-16T16:44:32.502339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2016-01-16T16:44:31.496313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you haven't posted your actual `wsgi.py` file. The exception you are getting is from `whitenoise`, but the file you posted uses `dj_static`.

To avoid the error you need to make sure the line:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proyecto_www.settings.staging")
```

comes before you import `whitenoise.django`.

This is due to a bug in Django which will be fixed in later versions.

Comment: I was actually getting the same error with whitenoise and dj_static, but you are right... the problem was the wrong order of importation